# Конвертация потока из multicast в icecast

Tags: ubuntu, vlc, broadcasting

Перед мной появилась задача конвертиртации потока `multicast` в `shoutcast` на сервере с операционной системой `Ubuntu 18.04`.

Для решения вопроса установил `VLC`. Теперь задача заключается в том, что нужно из первого источника получить поток и транслировать в другой. Кто может подсказать консольную команду запуска `VLC`, для того чтобы брать поток с нужного мне источника  и транскодировать в `shoutcast` и, в дальнейшем, перекодированный поток забрать уже на другой сервер?

Попробовал поднять с помощью FFMpeg
Получил такой вывод после ввода команды:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3-2~18.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='2~18.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
```

Я так понимаю FFMpeg не стартанул ?

Comment: кажется для таких целей проще использовать ffmpeg

Comment: Хорошо, я почитаю про него,

Comment: Это что получается за вход мне нужно указать мультикаст адрес радиостанции, затем указать аудио кодеки в каком виде я хочу получить сигнал и на выходе уже указать адрес второй сетевой карты откуда будет сниматься сигнал? или как в итоге мне получить данный перкодированный поток?

Comment: shoutcast может принимать поток на одном порту, и отдавать на другом. соответственно что-то вроде: ffmpeg -i udp:/_адрес_мультикаста -c:a libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ab 128k -content_type 'adui/mpeg' -f mp3 http://127.0.0.1:8080
можно погуглить  обёртку в виде скрипта, которая берет выхлоп от ffmpeg и отдаёт shoutcast

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8080 это по всей видимости шоуткаст сервер находящийся на той же машине? но можно использовать и адрес acecast или shoutcast уже работающего сервера, или любого другого что сможет принять то что ему отправляют?

Comment: да, для icecast кажется даже профиль есть

Comment: Попробовал создать паток но при старте ничего не происходит 

ffmpeg -re -i udp://234.109.235.1:1234 -c copy -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32k -ac 1 -content_type audio/mpeg -f mp3 icecast://данные для конекта@192.168.255.200:8000/domlive

Может я  что то делаю не так? 
как проверить идет ли захват с потока? а то может у меня маршруты еще прописать надо и он не может его захватить?

Comment: вместо  icecast://данные для конекта@192.168.255.200:8000/domlive 
укажите пусть к любому локальному файлу

Comment: Попробовал вот в таком виде: ffmpeg -re -i udp://234.109.235.1:1234 -c copy -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32k -ac 1 -content_type audio/mpeg -f mp3 /srv/media/test.mp3, ничего тоже не происходит папка медиа остается пустой фаил не записывается, или надо создать этот аудио фаил и в него писать?

Comment: нет, файл должен создаваться автоматически.
а поток на сервере виден? проверьте через ffprobe udp://234.109.235.1:1234
итогом должна быть информация о видео и аудио потоках

Comment: нет, информации о потоке не видно, ниже вывода библиотек зависшая строка, пробовал tcpdump по нужному мне хосту в мемент работы программы трафик на порт льется, а вот ffmpeg по каким то причинам его не забирает.

Comment: попробовал заменить вход на живой фаел, трафик на выходе тогда пошел и информация о входном и выходном сигнале тогда отобразилась.

Comment: может есть мысли почему ffmpeg не захватывает поток?

Comment: Скорее всего не хватает маршрута через интерфейсу с которого нужно забирать мультикаст. Попробуй: ip r add 234.109.235.0/24 dev eno1 - где eno1 - твой сетевой интерфейс на который приходит мультикаст

Comment: маршруты уже проверял, на всякий случай проверил еще раз и добавил новые 
к сожалению так и не появилось информации о потоке, 
tcpdump -i ens192 host 234.109.235.1 во время ffprobe udp://234.109.235.1:1234
показывает что поток на интерфейсе есть, по окончанию проверки пропадает поток на интерфейсе

Comment: а может быть какие то проблемы в сборке?
может в ручную собрать? только вот я не знаю какие модули нужны

Comment: В vlc этот мультикаст  виден? если нет значит проблемы в маршрутах или ОС. проверь параметры ядра, в частности net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter и net.ipv4.conf.Сетевая.rp_filter - попробуй их выставить в 0
Так: sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
если заработает потом добавить в файл /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: после выполнения команды sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
ffmpeg включился, суппер!!! прописал маршрут на выход там пакеты забегали.
огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: В процессе работы появился еще 1 вопрос,

а могу ли я закодированный в МР3 поток передать в MPEG-TS протоколе?

Comment: Вопрос снимается, -f mp3 меняем на mpegts и вуоля все помчалось)